# How do I highlight the position of horizontal and vertical line of cursor position in VIM?

Tags: vim

I was looking at the plugin and found the cursor position is highlighted with horizontal and vertical line.
I want it so much in my VIM but I can't find the plugin for it.

Does anyone know how to get this or how to set it up? It looks so cool

https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why a plugin? See `:help 'cursorline'` and `:help 'cursorcolumn'`.